# How do you "recieve" a promise from an interface or a promise's content?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, typescript, ionic-framework

I am asking this question because I do not understand the explanation provided on the questions I searched for, so this issue is probably a lot common. Im using another person's code in order to try and learn how does it work in order to replicate it. In one of the methods from an injectable, the original author returns a promise, and I am trying to get the promise's "insides" from a method where its been injected.

Ill post the code:
This is the author's code

```
getLists(){ 
    return this.isReady()
    .then(()=>{
      return this.database.executeSql("SELECT * from list", [])
      .then((data)=>{
        let lists = [];
        for(let i=0; i<data.rows.length; i++){
          lists.push(data.rows.item(i));
          console.log(i);
        }
        return lists;
      })
    })}
```

and here is what im more or less doing, but does not work because the types are not the same (string[] is not the same as Promise)

`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DatabaseService } from '../../app/database-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers:[DatabaseService],
})
export class HomePage {
  listas:string[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private service:DatabaseService ) {


  }
  getLists(){
  this.listas=this.service.getLists();
  }
  getList(){
    this.service.getList(0);
  }
  addList(){
    this.service.addList("Shazam");
  }
  deleteList(){
    this.service.deleteList(0);
  }

}`
```

Thank you for your patience and understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set `listas` when the data is ready:

```
 getLists(){
   this.service.getLists().then(lists => this.listas = lists);
  }
```

Or using another syntax:

```
 async getLists(){
   this.listas = await this.service.getLists();
  }
```

Comment: Your solution solved the problem, and I do now understand how it works. The .then calls a function when ready and passes lists to it as a parameter and then you assign that parameter to the scope's listas, am I right? Then where do you get lists's value from? Is it the return value from getLists (the one from the injectable)?

Comment: @kazekum, yes `lists` is what the promise resolves to.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your further understanding, the reason that you have a promise rather than a list is that the Promise.then function returns a promise.

In the return of your getLists() function, you return this.isReady().then(), which would return a promise to the caller.

The rest of that code is just modification of what gets returned in that promise, not of the promise itself.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Also the promise waits on returned promises to resolve before continuing into the next then()... ex: (also due to the lambda syntax this will only run in chrome)

```js
getPromise().then(a => console.log('a', a));

function getPromise() {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        res(1);
    }).then(b => {
        console.log('b', b);
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            setTimeout(() => res(2), 3000);
        })
    }).then(c => {
        console.log('c', c);
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            setTimeout(() => res(3), 3000);
        })
    });
}
```